# how do we implement passive health monitor in F5 BIG IP?

Tags: load-balancing, f5, big-ip

There is two type of health monitor in BIG IP F5. One is active and the other is passive. I want to implement the passive health monitor using TCP. Please let me know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Concepts](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-monitors-reference-12-0-0/2.html) (passive monitoring section)

[Configuration](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-monitors-reference-12-0-0/4.html) (inband section)